# Is it OK to create two objects with a single command?

Tags: python

I'd like to create two empty list objects. I tried to use

```
vList,sList = [],[]
```

and that seems to work. I never saw this in any manual (but my Python is still very basic). For non empty lists I'd say doing this harms the readability but is it OK to do this with identical, empty ones? Is this considered bad practice or **are there any bad side effects**?

Does the same hold for (empty) strings?

Comment: I think is OK, but better if you put space after the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no bad side effects, unless you use

```
vList = sList = []
```

Which references both variables to the same list.

I don't think PEP8 says anything about this, but I would say that splitting the assignments on two lines would read much better.

However, as @gorlum0 mentioned, if the objects are related and are relatively simple, it might be better to use tuple unpacking. If they're unrelated, then the reader will probably get quite confused trying to see why you've put them on one line.

Comment: in that case, changes in vList also take place in sList, right?

Comment: If the objects are _related_ and assignments are simple it might actually read better.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right way to do it. Even if multiple assignment doesn't seem very useful for simple cases like yours, consider something like this (unpacking a slightly more complicated sequence):

```
>>> d = { 'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z' }
>>> for i, (key, value) in enumerate(d.iteritems()):
...     print (i, key, value)
(0, 'a', 'x')
(1, 'c', 'z')
(2, 'b', 'y')
```

There are no harmful side effects if you keep in mind that the right hand side is fully evaluated before any assignments take place.